# HTML Form Not Sending Post

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have an HTML form that should be sending to a php form. I don't get a form not found error when the html loads, but the post action never occurs. When I go to the form via get, the code loads.

My html is:

```
<form class="form-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu4210" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="scripts/form-u4210.php"><!-- none box -->
      <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u4216-4"><!-- content -->
       <p>Submitting Form...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u4211-4"><!-- content -->
       <p>The server encountered an error.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u4229-4"><!-- content -->
       <p>Form received.</p>
      </div>
      <button class="submit-btn NoWrap rounded-corners clearfix grpelem" id="u4230-4" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" tabindex="3"><!-- content -->
       <div style="margin-top:-18px;height:18px;">
        <p>SUBMIT</p>
       </div>
      </button>
      <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu4217" data-required="true"><!-- none box -->
       <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u4218-4" for="widgetu4217_input"><!-- content --><span class="actAsPara">Email:</span></label>
       <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u4220-4"><!-- content --><input class="wrapped-input" type="text" id="widgetu4217_input" name="custom_U4217" tabindex="1"/><label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt" id="widgetu4217_prompt" for="widgetu4217_input"><span class="actAsPara">Please Enter Your First Name</span></label></span>
      </div>
      <div class="fld-grp clearfix grpelem" id="widgetu4221" data-required="true"><!-- none box -->
       <label class="fld-label actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u4224-4" for="widgetu4221_input"><!-- content --><span class="actAsPara">Password:</span></label>
       <span class="fld-input NoWrap actAsDiv clearfix grpelem" id="u4222-4"><!-- content --><input class="wrapped-input" type="text" id="widgetu4221_input" name="custom_U4221" tabindex="2"/><label class="wrapped-input fld-prompt" id="widgetu4221_prompt" for="widgetu4221_input"><span class="actAsPara">Please Enter Your Last Name</span></label></span>
      </div>
     </form>
```

My php is:

```
<?php 
    // add in error reporting
    ini_set('display_errors','On');
    ini_set('html_errors',0);
    error_reporting(-1);

    require('form_process.php');
    require('../vendor/autoload.php');
    use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;

    //echo($_POST["email"]);
    //echo($_POST["password"]);

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
    {
        header("Location: ../question-explanation.html");die();

    }  
    else if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") 
    {
        header("Location: ../question-explanation.html");die();


    }

?>
```

Comment: Why are you using JS redirects in a PHP script?

Comment: @JayBlanchard it was a solution that I saw here. I tried to use header, but that didn't work either

Comment: Add `print_r($_POST)` to the top of the script and resubmit to see what you get.

Comment: You are trying to access two different paths in your project. Pay close attention to `../question-explanation.html`

Comment: @Willi Thanks for the catch. Unfortunately that didn't fix it

Comment: @JayBlanchard I added it and nothing changed. When I submit the form, it's almost as if it reloads (the input is cleared and I get a loading circle on my browser)

Comment: You should really either be using `header("Location: /question-explanation.html");die();` in your PHP file or you should be handling the form submit with JS on the front end and doing a redirect based on a response.

Comment: And I really don't think the browser will parse that JS returned as text, but in any case you want `window.top.location` not `window.location.assign`

Comment: you sure you're running this off a webserver with php installed and as `http://localhost` or are you doing `file:///` directly in your web browser? or is this a hosted site? Your *"When I go to the form via get, the code loads."* suggests that you're not running this off a server or it's not properly configured.

Comment: @Chase I changed to using header and I got the same effect: it works via get, but not post

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I'm doing this by using localhost with xampp. Could that be the problem?

Comment: in order for php to be parsed, you need to run this as `http://localhost/file.xxx`, so it's unsure how you're running it. The `WindowsAzure` stuff, that I don't know anything about, so I won't be of much help there. So, how are you running it as and what's the server's OS?

Comment: I'm running it as: http://localhost/olivia/oliviahtml/log-in.php. The login page successfully displays. I can also access the php page (http://localhost/olivia/oliviahtml/scripts/loginScript.php) the same way. I'm running it using xampp v3.2.2 @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: So if GET works but POST doesn't, that tells you something. I would add a `die();` after each echo in the conditional to prevent further parsing. I would also try and POST to the script directly (using something like curl) to see if it is a form problem or just a problem identifying POST in your script.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I don't think it needed here or even necessary in this case,however when you need to save redirect address in browser history you'll use client side redirects (javascript or html refresh header)

Comment: @DMop, have you checked php log to see if there are errors in running php? in your development machine you need to set php to show all errors on page.

Comment: @AaA I just checked the logs and there's no errors there

Comment: if your `get` works but not `post`, please add `../` to your `POST` Url. also print request headers on your page to see if the request is actually a `POST` or `GET` and not `PUT` or `OPTION`

Comment: @AaA I just added ../ and that didn't work. How would I go about printing the request headers?

Comment: try [Fetch all HTTP headers from current request](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php)

Comment: hey brah i hope this will help you, it is simple and easy to understand https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNuCNQDGBnk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmdunkXQlZw

Comment: @AaA when I run it via get, I get:
Host: localhost Connection: keep-alive User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es-US;q=0.8,es;q=0.7 Cookie: _xsrf=2|516ef8de|e904d19e2f88436e94dd27860370017f|1512462607

but via post, the page never changes to display anything

Comment: @NoobProgrammer thanks! I think I'm just gonna have to go to that. Idk why this isn't working. It seems like it's so close

Comment: @DMop Sure :) Cheers! :D

Answer (score 0):

The error was generated via Javascript automatically created by adobe muse. For people with similar errors, try turning JS off and see if your errors persist.

Comment: Funny you should post that. I had a feeling you had some JS happening, which is what my "Spidey sense" was telling me, but I failed to mention that.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner well you have good instincts. Thanks for your help

Comment: welcome. You know why I thought that? The "id"'s, it usually suggests it.

Comment: Ahh that helps a lot! I'm going back and removing the JS now @FunkFortyNiner